# Request payload size exceeds limit while exporting image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-5p

I am getting:

> Request payload size exceeds limit

while exporting image from google earth engine

This is the code:

```
// Lab: Linear Regression
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("users/enigma_srl/MADHYAPRADESH_DISTRICTS");

/// This function adds a band representing the image timestamp.

var addTime = function (image) {
return image.addBands (image.metadata('system:time_start') .divide (1000*60*60*24*365));
};

// and map the time band function over it.

var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2")

.filterDate('2019-01-01', '2022-12-31')

.map(addTime)

.filterBounds (ROI);

var trend = collection.select(['system:time_start', 'NO2_column_number_density'])

// Compute the linear trend over time.

 .reduce(ee. Reducer.linearFit());

// Display the trend with increasing slopes in green, decreasing in red.


Map.centerObject (ROI, 6);

Map.addLayer(trend.clip(ROI), {min: 0, max: [   -0.00051, 0.0192, 1000], bands: ['scale', 'scale', 'offset']}, 'Air Quality trend over MP');

Export.image.toDrive({

  image: trend ,

  description: 'Linear fit',

  region: ROI,

  scale: 30,
});
```

How do I export the image?

Answer (score 0):

Your collection is getting in-lined into the Export call because you used it as the region.  You shouldn't ever use a collection as a geometry.
Use `clipToCollection` when clipping with it, and  `collection.geometry().bounds()` for the region in the Export.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#if-you-need-to-clip-with-a-complex-collection,-use-cliptocollection